# Jquery appendTo() appends the element two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little script that creates a table hover a div, this script creates the `<tr>` and `<td>` dynamically depends of the width and height of the `<div>` this is executed from a for sentence but the appendTo is executed two times, in the next image we can see that the attributes and id that I put in  the elements is duplicated and this attribute corresponds at the value of the "for" variable.

This is my complete page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content-map">
 <img id="main-reference" src="puestos.png" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"/>
</div>

</body>
<script>
 var table = '<table id="grilla" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>';
 var tr = '<tr id="current-row"><tr>';
 var td = '<td><td>';
 var maxHeight = 1200;
 var maxWidth = 700;
 var height = $( "#main-reference" ).get( 0 ).naturalWidth;
 var width = $( "#main-reference" ).get( 0 ).naturalHeight;

 if ( maxHeight > height && maxWidth > width ) {
  $( "#content-map" ).css( { "width": width, "height": height } );
 } else {
  $( "#main-reference" ).css( { "display": "block" } );
  $( "#content-map" ).css( { "width": $( "#main-reference" ).width(), "height": $( "#main-reference" ).height() } );
 }

 var finalHeight = $( "#content-map" ).height();
 var finalWidth = $( "#content-map" ).width();
 var numberOfRows = Math.floor( finalHeight / 30 );
 var numberOfCols = Math.floor( finalWidth / 30 );
 var tdHeight = finalHeight / numberOfRows;

 $( "#main-reference" ).css( { "display": "none" } );
 $( table ).appendTo( "#content-map" );

 for ( var i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++ ) {
  $( tr ).appendTo( "#grilla" ).attr( "row-number", i );
  for ( var j = 0; j <= numberOfCols; j++ ) {
   console.log( "numberOfCols[" + numberOfCols + "]" + ":" + j );
   $( td ).appendTo( "#current-row" ).css( { "height": tdHeight } ).attr( "id", j );
  }
  $( "#current-row" ).removeAttr( "id" );
 }
</script>
</html>
```

and results in :

[image]

Comment: voted to close as the issue was a typo

Answer (score 4):

you need to close the `tr` and `td` elements :

```
var tr = '<tr id="current-row"></tr>';
var td = '<td></td>';
```

Comment: This is it! Malformed strings passed into jquery will result in them being parsed in unpredictable ways. Always carefully form all HTML going into the jquery() function.